# How to save an image in Sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i want to save an image in Sqlite in BOMB format first
& then want to dispaly it in the tableviewController's cell
plaese suggest me something for that.
I m rookie in Iphone development.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a rookie, take it one step at a time. First get some static images, as part of the app, to display correctly. Then get the interaction going to download (or take using camera?) your image to a path in the Caches folder. Only then begin to think about the sqlite part.

Ask *specific* questions here after trying hard, and you will get answers!